# How to add button in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to add a  button before or after the "create" Button in Tree view That calls the action of another view.

But as I tried header tag is not working in xml to add the button in header of the odoo.

Comment: In what view do you want's to add button?

Comment: Hi @mokiSRB, I wanna add a button before or after the default create button .

Comment: That button can't be placed into the typical view extensions (`ir.ui.view` records). You need to extend the whole odoo client (QWeb view) to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Can you please share some reference which helps me to do this, Because I am not more familiar with js.

Comment: Look into [OCA Web Modules](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/8.0) to get a hint, what you will have to do to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend `ListView.buttons` QWEB template.

Define a QWEB template under `static/src/xml` which adds the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.oe_list_add" t-operation="after">
            <button t-if="widget.dataset.model == 'model_name'" class="oe_button oe_my_button oe_highlight" type="button">My Button</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Use `JavaScript` to define the logic of the button ( create a file under `static/src/js`):

```
openerp.module_name = function(instance){

instance.web.ListView.include({
    load_list: function(data) {
        this._super(data);
        if (this.$buttons) {
            this.$buttons.find('.oe_my_button').off().click(this.proxy('do_the_job')) ;
        }
    },
    do_the_job: function () {

        this.do_action({
            name: _t("View name"),
            type: "ir.actions.act_window",
            res_model: "object",
            domain : [],
            views: [[false, "list"],[false, "tree"]],
            target: 'new',
            context: {},
            view_type : 'list',
            view_mode : 'list'
        });
    }
});
}
```

Define a new view that will add module assets (**module_name_view.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
      <template id="assets_backend_module_name" name="module_name assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/module_name/static/src/js/script.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

Edit `__openerp__.py` and add the following sections:

```
'data': [
    'module_name_view.xml',
    ...
],
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/*.xml'],
```

Look at [Building Interface Extensions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html) for more details.

Comment: @user_123 Check question `Tags`. It is not designed for `Odoo 11`.